# Lua file writing problems

Tags: file-io, lua

I create a string, print it to see what it looks like, then write it to a file. However the output file is empty and it prints nil. More info in the comments, I'm not really sure what's the cause of the problem here

```
function main()
    local x = 80
    local y = 25
    local str = ""

    str = str..'map = {\n'

    for i = 1, (y - 1) do
        str = str..'{'

        for i = 1, (x - 1) do
            str = str..'" ",'
        end

        str = str..'" "'
        str = str..'},\n'
    end

    str = str..'{'

    for i = 1, (x - 1) do
        str = str..'" ",'
    end

    str = str..'" "'
    str = str..'}\n'
    str = str..'}'

    --Prints it without problems here
    print(str)

    local file,err = io.open("mapTable.mpt","w")

    if not file then
        return err
    end

    --HERE STR IS NIL???
    print(str)

    file:write(str)
    file:close()
end


local s,err = pcall(main)
if not s then
    print(err)
else
    print("Application ran successfully.")
end
io.read()
```

Comment: `if not f then`? You never declare the variable `f`.

Comment: Changed it to file instead of f but that obviously doesnt fix anything :/

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine for me...

Comment: This is not http://codereview.stackexchange.com but you can avoid lots of string concatenations by writing directly to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you aren't raising an error in main, you just return an error string so pcall thinks all is ok and you always end up in the second branch of your if block. Do this instead:

```
function main()
    ...
    if not file then
        error(err)
    end
    ...
end

local s,err = pcall(main)
if not s then
    print('error caught:', err)
else
    print("Application ran successfully.")
end
```

Note that `err` that gets printed will have additional info, it won't be equal to `err` given to the `error` function.